# Divide area into equal parts

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp, skia

I read the documentation from skiasharp.. I am interested in how I can divide the surface of a shape (rectangle or polygon) into equal parts. For example, divide the surface into 6 equal parts and paint those parts with two colors according to the even-odd principle (something like football grass field texture). I did not find any similar example in the documentation.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Be more specific, illustrate an example, show some code, what you tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maku, thanks for your answer. I resolved this.
I needed something like this in the picture:

[image]

And my code for this result looks like this:

```
    using System;
using SkiaSharp;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

void Draw(SKCanvas canvas, int width, int height)
{
            float scale = 22.0f;
            SKPath path = new SKPath();
            List<SKPoint> AreaCenters = new List<SKPoint>();
            List<SKPath> OutlinePaths = new List<SKPath>();
            OutlinePaths.Clear();
            AreaCenters.Clear();
            AreaCenters.Add(new SKPoint(0.0f, 0.0f));
            AreaCenters.Add(new SKPoint(200.0f, 0.0f));
            AreaCenters.Add(new SKPoint(100f, 200.0f));
            float scaleFactor =  1.1f;
            var scaleMatrix = SKMatrix.MakeSkew(scale * 2.0f, scale * scaleFactor);
            
            SKPaint fillColor1 = new SKPaint
            {
                IsAntialias = true,
                Color = SKColors.Transparent,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
                StrokeWidth = 3,
                StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Square
            };

            SKPaint fillColor2 = new SKPaint
            {
                IsAntialias = true,
                Color = SKColors.DarkGreen,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
                StrokeWidth = 3,
                StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Square
            };

            SKPaint lineColor = new SKPaint
            {
                IsAntialias = true,
                Color = SKColors.Orange,
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
                StrokeWidth = 4.0f
            };

            
                fillColor2.PathEffect = SKPathEffect.Create2DLine(scale, scaleMatrix);

            

            if (AreaCenters.Count > 0)
            {
                path.MoveTo((AreaCenters[0]));
                foreach (SKPoint p in AreaCenters.ToArray())
                {
                    path.LineTo((p));
                }
                path.Close();

                //path.Transform(TransformationMatrix);
                //OutlinePath = path;
                //this.OutlinePaths.Add(this.OutlinePath);
                OutlinePaths.Add(path);
                canvas.Save();

                canvas.DrawPath(path, lineColor);
                if (AreaCenters.Count > 2)
                    canvas.ClipPath(OutlinePaths[0]);

                SKPath sKPath = new SKPath();
                sKPath.AddPath(path, -scale, -scale * 2f);
                sKPath.AddPath(path, -scale, scale * 2f);
                sKPath.AddPath(path, scale, -scale * 2f);
                sKPath.AddPath(path, scale, scale * 2f);
                canvas.DrawPath(sKPath, fillColor1);
                canvas.DrawPath(path, fillColor2);
                canvas.DrawPath(path, lineColor);
                fillColor1.Dispose();
                fillColor2.Dispose();
                canvas.Restore();
            }
}
```

For this purposes I'm used SKMatrix.CreateSkew() (or SKMatrix.MakeSkew()) method in skiasharp.